# Aptana Studio 3 + Zend Framework SETUP

Tags: zend-framework, aptana

I am just starting out with php and I decided to try and use zend framework too. I would like to use Aptana Studio 3 as my IDE (I am using windows 7), and I am trying to get everything setup so I can start developing.

Can anyone point me to a guide on how to setup this environment? I have tried following lots of guides and can't get it to work. I have installed wamp which gave me php and apache. I then installed ZF and added the zf.bat etc to my php directory and can run the zf commands from the console. I have generated a quicstart project but when I start debugging my browser opens

```
http://127.0.0.1:8020/MyProject/quickstart/public/index.php
```

and the page just shows bootstrap() ->run();

I don't really know what to do now, can anyone help?

Comment: Have you set up a virtual host on apache with a sub domain for the project?